# A-Frame: standalone environment (ala PhoneGap)

Tags: aframe

Are there any options for packaging an A-Frame application into a standalone form? Sort of like how PhoneGap packages webapps?

I imagine the solution would need to package all HTML/JS files and resources together with a standalone browser? And then launch with 'headset mode' on by default?

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame apps are just webapp, so try the existing toolchains like Cordova or Phonegap. There may be issues and your mileage may vary though as we don't put much effort towards those use cases. There are several issues filed for Cordova + A-Frame on GitHub for an introductory read.

It seems though recent webvr-polyfill issues may not be friendly for WebViews: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1940

Answer (score 0):

I've been using crosswalk lately, all the latest APIs and no browser compatibility problems.

It's very easy to add on to an existing html5 project : https://crosswalk-project.org/